# add a circle on a group on click not appearing correctly with fabricjs

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have the following code for a cusomt object named App

```
App.prototype.createCanvas = function (id){
    var domElement, canvas;
    domElement = document.getElementById(id);
    this.imageUrl = domElement.getAttribute('data-url');
    this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas(id);
    this.canvas.setWidth(800);
    this.canvas.setHeight(600);
    this.loadMainImage();

};

App.prototype.loadMainImage = function(){
    var width, height, aspectRatio;
    var _that = this;
    fabric.Image.fromURL(this.imageUrl, function(oImg){
        _that.mainImage = oImg;
        console.log('loading image');
        if (_that.mainImage.getWidth() > _that.mainImage.getHeight()){
            _that.mainImage.scaleToWidth(600);
        }else{
            _that.mainImage.scaleToHeight(600);
        }
        _that.group = new fabric.Group([_that.mainImage]);
        _that.group.hasRotatingPoint = false;
        //_that.group.add(oImg);
        _that.group.selectable = true;
        _that.group.angle = 0;
        _that.canvas.add(_that.group);
        _that.group.center();
        _that.group.setCoords();
        _that.canvas.renderAll();
        console.log(_that.group.getTop());
        console.log(_that.group.getLeft());
        console.log(_that.group.getWidth());
        console.log(_that.group.getHeight());

    });
};


App.prototype.startCalibration = function(){
    console.log("circle A:"+ this.circleA);
    console.log("circle B"+ this.circleB);
    var _that = this;
    alert("Click on xray to add two points for calibrations");
    var distance;
    this.pointA = null;
    this.pointB = null;

    if (this.calibrate){
        setPoints = function (e){
            var event = e.e;
            console.log(this.group.getLocalPointer(event));
            if (this.pointA == null){
                this.pointA = {
                    x: this.group.getLocalPointer(event).x,
                    y: this.group.getLocalPointer(event).y
                };

                console.log("pointA:{x:"+this.pointA.x+",y:"+this.pointA.y+"}");
                this.circleA = new fabric.Circle({
                    radius:5,
                    fill:"red",
                    left:this.pointA.x,
                    top: this.pointA.y
                });

                console.log("circleA top"+this.circleA.getTop());
                console.log("circleA left"+this.circleA.getLeft());

                this.group.addWithUpdate(this.circleA);


            }else if (this.pointB == null) {
                this.pointB = {
                    x: this.group.getLocalPointer(event).x,
                    y: this.group.getLocalPointer(event).y
                };
                this.circleB = new fabric.Circle({
                    radius:5,
                    fill:"red",
                    top:this.pointB.y,
                    left: this.pointB.x
                });

                this.group.addWithUpdate(this.circleB);


            }
            this.canvas.renderAll();

            if (this.pointB !==null && this.pointA !== null){

                $('#distanceValue').attr('disabled', false);
            }
        }.bind(this);

        this.group.selectable = false;
        this.canvas.renderAll();
        this.group.on('mouseup', setPoints);
    }
};
```

The last function is called by an external javascript file. What I want to do is to add to points on an image loaded on the canvas within a group and callibrate the distance between to points. The user will provide the physical distance between to points and the programm will do the callibration. The circles are just to provide the visual But they won't appear where I have clicked. The output of the console.log is

```
groupTop: 150
groupLeft: 100
groupWidth:600
groupHeight:300
circle A:null
circle B: null
Object {x: 37, y: 28}
pointA:{x:37,y:28}
circleA top 37
circleA left 28
```

So although the circle's top and left are correct to the groups coordinates circles won't appear as it should. They appear more to the right but at the same height. Should I use originX and originY instead?

The second issue if it can be resolved here or open a new question is that the remove function won't work

Answer (score 0):

since version 1.4.0 FabricJS  uses TOP LEFT corner for positioning.

If you want to make the circles appears exactly where you clicked, frist thing to try is to add to circle options `"originX: 'center', originY: 'center'"` So the circle will be centered on the point you clicked.